# Can magnesium chloride absorb water and ammonia at the same time?

Tags: solubility, molecules

Anhydrous magnesium chloride will absorb ammonia to the tune of ($\ce{Mg(NH3)6Cl2}$).
Incidentally, magnesium chloride is usually a hexahydrate ($\ce{MgCl2(H2O)6}$) at STP.

My question is, could magnesium chloride be induced to absorb both ammonia and water at the same time? Since both of the absorbed molecules in question are close in shape, size, structure and since six seems to be the occupancy limit for either one (at STP), would they be able to coexsist?
For example, could I expose some magnesium chloride dihydrate to ammonia and get
($\ce{Mg(NH3)4Cl2(H2O)2}$)?

Comment: anhydrous magnesium chloride will adsorb both, however composition of the phase formed is not easily predictable from general principle